# How to concisely and elegantly validate the elements of a list in Common Lisp

Tags: validation, configuration, common-lisp

I am trying to validate (in Common Lisp) the lines of a config file. I have read them into a list of lists, in the form of ((lineno parm value &optional freq start end) (...)).
I want to be able to validate each line of the config file, identify and display the errors found, and if any errors are found to end the function with a NIL result.

I have a working function, but it seems clunky. I also don't know how to pass a NIL from the loop statement as the final result of my function.

This is my function ...

```
(defun validate-config-params (config-params)
  "Validate the parsed config parameters."
  (loop for config-param in config-params
          ; config-param is the entire config form (lineno parm value [freq [start [end]]])
        for param = (cadr config-param)
        for line-number = (car config-param)
        for error-message = ""
        with error-count = 0
        do (unless (or (null param) (and (listp param) (every #'atom param))) 
            (setf error-message (format nil "~A Incorrect format." error-message)))
          (unless (symbolp (first param)) 
            (setf error-message (format nil "~A 1st parm not a symbol." error-message)))
          (unless (or (null (second param)) (numberp (second param))) 
            (setf error-message (format nil "~A 2nd parm not a number." error-message)))
          (unless (or (null (third param)) (symbolp (third param))) 
            (setf error-message (format nil "~A 3rd parm not a symbol." error-message)))
          (unless (or (null (fourth param)) (numberp (fourth param))) 
            (setf error-message (format nil "~A 4th parm not a number." error-message)))
          (unless (or (null (fifth param)) (numberp (fifth param))) 
            (setf error-message (format nil "~A 5th parm not a number." error-message)))
          (cond ((not (STRING= error-message ""))
                  (format T "Line ~A: ~A~%       ~A~%" line-number param error-message)
                  (setf error-message "")
                  (incf error-count)
                  nil)
                (t 'good)))
  (unless (> error-count 0)))
```

For config-parms ...

```
(defparameter config-params '((1 NIL) 
 (2 NIL) 
 (3 (PENSION 1000 FORTNIGHTLY))
 (4 (DEEMING-LOW-RATE (/ 0.25 100))) 
 (5 (DEEMING-HIGH-RATE (/ 2.25 100)))
 (6 (DEEMING-LOW-THR 100000)) 
 (7 (INTEREST 7.2 YEARLY))))
```

... I get this result ...

```
* (validate-config-params config-params)
Line 4: (DEEMING-LOW-RATE (/ 0.25 100))
        Incorrect format. 2nd parm not a number.
Line 5: (DEEMING-HIGH-RATE (/ 2.25 100))
        Incorrect format. 2nd parm not a number.
NIL
```

... which is what I expect, but it seems bulky. If I set lines 4 & 5 to plain numbers (ie 0.25 &  2.25), it does validate correctly but still returns NIL.

How can I clean this up?

Comment: That last line _always_ returns `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

Is a `pension` always made of an amount and a period? and `deeming-low-rate` only made of an amount? In the spirit of [Parse don't validate](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2019/11/05/parse-don-t-validate/) from Alexis King  (which is written with static types in mind), I would try to normalize the data into values that have a predictable shape and/or type, ie. a set of interfaces that don't need to always check if the data is well-formed. For example you could make sure that all configurations are in fact turned into property lists as follows:

```
(:row 2 :freq ... :start ... :end ... :category 'categories:pension :amount ...)
```

So that later, you can call `(getf entry field)` for any field and know your values are normalized. Note for example that the `pension` symbol is turned into a known symbol in a package you know, `categories`, so that you can prevent unknown symbols to be entered in the configuration (something that `symbolp` alone doesn't prevent).

You can also turn to CLOS and write classes:

```
(defpackage :stack-overflow (:use :cl))
(in-package :stack-overflow)

(defclass configuration ()
  ((entries :initarg :entries
            :reader configuration-entries
            :initform nil)))

(defclass entry ()
  ((line :initarg :line :reader entry-line)))

(defclass empty-entry (entry) ())
```

Below I define *mixin* classes that can be used to share common fields:

```
(defclass has-amount ()
  ((amount :initarg :amount :reader amount)))

(defclass has-period ()
  ((period :initarg :period :reader period)))
```

For example:

```
(defclass pension (entry has-amount has-period) ())
(defclass interest (entry has-amount has-period) ())
(defclass deeming-low-threshold (entry has-amount) ())
```

When building your objects you can check that the values are well-formed:

```
(defmethod initialize-instance :after ((c configuration) &key &allow-other-keys)
  (with-slots (entries) c
    (check-type entries sequence)
    (map () (lambda (e) (check-type e entry)) entries)))

(defmethod initialize-instance :after ((e entry) &key &allow-other-keys)
  (with-slots (line) e
    (check-type line (integer 0))))
```

It is sufficient to define methods for mixins, and then the child classes will also perfom these checks:

```
(defmethod initialize-instance :after ((entry has-amount) &key &allow-other-keys)
  (with-slots (amount) entry
    (check-type amount real)))

(defmethod initialize-instance :after ((entry has-period) &key &allow-other-keys)
  (with-slots (period) entry
    (let ((normalized (find period '(yearly fortnightly) :test 'string-equal)))
      (assert normalized () "Unknown period ~s" period)
      (setf period normalized))))
```

For example, this is a valid configuration:

```
(make-instance 'configuration
               :entries (list (make-instance 'pension 
                                             :line 0
                                             :period "yearly"
                                             :amount 5.5)))
#<CONFIGURATION {1012D817C3}>
```

And you can write code that dispatches on the type of entry (e.g. pension, etc.) that is actually represented by each entry.

The function you will actually call to build your values from the raw list is:

```
(defun parse-config (config)
  (destructuring-bind (line &optional entry) config
    (destructuring-bind (&optional param value freq start end) entry
      (let ((class (find-class* (or param 'empty-entry))))
        (make-instance class
                       :line line
                       :amount value
                       :period freq
                       :start start
                       :end end)))))
```

Here I assume `find-class*` is like `find-class`, but tries to restrict the set of supported classes (it depends on whether you trust the raw list or not).

It loosely accepts anything that could be an entry, then delegate the actual validation to initializer methods. Notice that it doesn't catch the case where a config doesn't use a keyword argument that was provided.

You can directly call `(mapcar #'parse-config config-params)` to see that there is an exception happening when building some config. Now, you can handle the errors, collect them and only keep the valid entries:

```
(defun parse-config-params (config-params)
  "Parse config parameters."
  (let ((errors nil) (valid nil))
    (dolist (c config-params)
      (multiple-value-bind (result error) (ignore-errors (parse-config c))
        (if error
            (push error errors)
            (push result valid))))
    (values (make-instance 'configuration :entries (nreverse valid))
            (nreverse errors))))
```

The function returns two values, a configuration and a list of errors:

```
(defparameter config-params '((1 NIL) 
 (2 NIL) 
 (3 (PENSION 1000 FORTNIGHTLY))
 (4 (DEEMING-LOW-RATE (/ 0.25 100))) 
 (5 (DEEMING-HIGH-RATE (/ 2.25 100)))
 (6 (DEEMING-LOW-THRESHOLD 100000)) 
 (7 (INTEREST 7.2 YEARLY))))


(parse-config-params config-params)
#<CONFIGURATION {1014613503}>
(#<SB-PCL:CLASS-NOT-FOUND-ERROR DEEMING-LOW-RATE {1014611163}>
 #<SB-PCL:CLASS-NOT-FOUND-ERROR DEEMING-HIGH-RATE {1014611183}>)
```

Each valid entry in the configuration has a specific type:

```
(map () 
     #'describe 
     (configuration-entries 
       (parse-config-params config-params)))
```

Here is the output (redacted for space):

```
#<EMPTY-ENTRY {1014D2FE73}>
  LINE                           = 1

#<EMPTY-ENTRY {1014D2FEF3}>
  LINE                           = 2

#<PENSION {1014D2FF83}>
  PERIOD                         = FORTNIGHTLY
  AMOUNT                         = 1000
  LINE                           = 3

#<DEEMING-LOW-THRESHOLD {1014D3FF73}>
  AMOUNT                         = 100000
  LINE                           = 6

#<INTEREST {1014D47FF3}>
  PERIOD                         = YEARLY
  AMOUNT                         = 7.2
  LINE                           = 7
```

Alternatively, you could install *restarts* around `parse-config` to allow the user to fill-in the required fields, or the give a different config. This can be useful if you have a long list of data that you need to curate interactively. Or you could print the error to standard error, etc. By relying on the exception mechanism you can decide later how you collect and handle errors.

Comment: On SBCL 2.3.4_linux, `(defmethod initialize-instance :after ((e entry) &key &allow-other-keys) (check-type (entry-line e) (integer 0)))` raises a `STYLE-WARNING condition`with `Undefined function: (SETF ENTRY-LINE)`. I don't know why because we don't SETF entry-line... By making entry-line an `:accessor` in class entry instead of a `:reader`, there's no more warning.

Comment: @JérômeRadix Thanks! indeed I tried to use only readers because supposedly this is read-only data and there is no validation done on value change (this could be implemented too but I decided not to here); I'll use `with-slots` which relies on `slot-value` instead (which is okay to use in the implementation package in my opinion).

Comment: @JérômeRadix I added a paragraph to explain, this is not implemented but this was more a hint to indicate that in practice I would not call directly find-class but one that first check if the class is suited for this particular usage.

Answer (score 1):

I'd return both the validation result (t or nil) and the errors.  You can then decide what to do with the errors (such as printing them) independently.

An *ad hoc* definition could be like this:

```lisp
(defun validate-config-parameters (config-parameters)
  (let ((errors (loop :for (line (param value freq start end)) :in config-parameters
                      :unless (symbolp param)
                        :collect (list line 'param param "not a symbol")
                      :unless (or (null value) (numberp value))
                        :collect (list line 'value value "not a number")
                      :unless (or (null freq) (symbolp freq))
                        :collect (list line 'freq freq "not a symbol")
                      :unless (or (null start) (numberp start))
                        :collect (list line 'start start "not a number")
                      :unless (or (null end) (numberp end))
                        :collect (list line 'end end "not a number"))))
    (values (endp errors)
            errors)))
```

Some notes:

- the `for` loop keyword can destructure
- we can now get multiple errors in a single line, instead of only the last one

Comment: "instead of only the last one": It seems like the code concatenates to `error-message` so it does include all, but does not tell what parameter had what problem. Also I'm guesssing only the `freq` one needs to check for `nil`

Comment: Oh, you're right, I stopped reading after `setf error-message`.  But the null check must be at all optional arguments, it just is redundant with symbolp (unifies to just symbolp).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I might solve this problem.  This stems from my view that the interesting thing (the *only* interesting thing) about Lisp is that it is a machine for creating programming languages, and that many of these languages will compose with each other.  This means that if you have *n* extensions to Lisp ('little languages', 'libraries') then you can compose them together to get of the order of 2^*n* languages.  Each of those languages might be something you use only once, and a single program might use many of them.  That fills people with dread but it should not: if the composition works (if the extensions are orthogonal) then, if you know each extension, you *already know* a number of languages which is exponential in the number of extensions.

`loop` is the antithesis of this approach: it's a great glob of non-orthogonal facilities piled into one macro.  Some `loop` implementations even allow you to add more to the pile, which does not make things better from the point of view expressed above.

In this case you probably want to do two things: you want to check a bunch of objects (here entries from the config file) and probably report against them, while recording if you actually did report anything.

So one way of doing this is to have a special little `reporting` macro (which is, of course, a little language which extends CL) which deals with both reporting against objects, and will tell you if any reports are generated.  If you're iterating over objects and making several checks against each one, then it's natural for uses of this macro to return two values: a list of objects for which reports were generated, and, for each such object, a list of reports.

To write this macro I'm going to use Tim Bradshaw's [collecting](https://tfeb.github.io/tfeb-lisp-hax/#collecting-lists-forwards-and-accumulating-collecting) tools, which allows you to collect values into lists (and indeed accumulate them in other ways) in a much more general and flexible way than `loop` does.

I will also use his [metatronic macros](https://tfeb.github.io/tfeb-lisp-hax/#metatronic-macros), to make writing the macro less painful.  Again this is a little extension to CL which will compose with other such extensions.

```
(defmacro/m reporting ((&optional (to '*error-output*))
                       &body forms)
  `(let ((<current-object> '<no-object>)
         <current-reports>
         (<to> ,to))
     (with-collectors (<object> <reports>)
       (flet ((report (object control &rest args)
                (declare (dynamic-extent args))
                (unless (eq object <current-object>)
                  (unless (eq <current-object> '<no-object>)
                    (<object> <current-object>)
                    (<reports> (collector-contents <current-reports>)))
                  (setf <current-reports> (make-collector)
                        <current-object> object))
                (let ((report (apply #'format nil control args)))
                  (when <to>
                    (format t "~&~A~%" report))
                  (collect-into <current-reports> report))))
         ,@forms
         (unless (eq <current-object> '<no-object>)
           (<object> <current-object>)
           (<reports> (collector-contents <current-reports>)))))))
```

This could obviously be varied depending on what you want.

Now, to actually check the entries an obvious approach is to use pattern-matching.  There are various pattern-matching extensions for CL, some of which can do fancy type-checking in patterns.  I'm *not* going to use those, because I don't want a match just to fail, I want to know the details of which bit failed so I can report on that.  So I'll use another of Tim Bradshaw's extensions: [`destructuring-mach`](https://tfeb.github.io/dsm/).  This provides a construct which is like a combination of `destructuring-bind` and `case`, which is what I think is useful here.

Finally, I think there's no real way not to actually explicitly check a bunch of things, since I want to be able to generate reports on them.

So, here is the whole thing:

```
(defun validate-config-params (config-params &optional (stream *error-output*))
  (multiple-value-bind (bad-lines reports)
      (reporting (stream)
        (dolist (line config-params)
          (destructuring-match line
            ((line-number params)
             (:when (typep line-number '(integer 0)))
             (destructuring-match params
               ((param value &optional (freq nil) (start 0) (end 0))
                (unless (symbolp param)
                  (report line "~4D: param not a symbol" line-number))
                (unless (realp value)
                  (report line "~4D: value not a real" line-number))
                (unless (symbolp freq)
                  (report line "~4D: freq not a symbol" line-number))
                (unless (realp start)
                  (report line "~4D: start not a real" line-number))
                (unless (realp end)
                  (report line "~4D: end not a real" line-number)))
               (())
               (otherwise
                (report line "~4D: hopeless line" line-number))))
            (otherwise
             (report line "completely hopeless line ~A" line)))))
    (values (null bad-lines) bad-lines reports)))
```

Note in particular that this uses argument defaulting in the `destructuing-match` cases in order to make the type checks simpler: if you don't gie a `start` and `end` they'll be `0` which is a legal value.

Obviously there is more you can do here.  And equally obviously for a once-off hack you might not want to do this much.  What I am pretty sure you *do* want to do is avoid the awful explicit `(second ...)` stuff: bind the parts of the entry to variables with useful names.